# Django REST url does not match patterns

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to keep URL's prefix with app names in the main urls.py file. This way I will avoid collision of endpoints in other apps under the same project.

```
# project/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/accounts/', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/users/', include('users.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/transactions/', include('transactions.urls')),
    url(r'^auth-token-auth', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

For instance, I am including `accounts.urls` with following content:

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^', AccountListView.as_view()),
     url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', AccountDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

By doing this way `/api/v1/accounts/1` pattern does not match `AccountDetailView`. It always returns the first view `AccountListView`

The most interesting thing is when I change `urlpatterns` definition in the way provided below. All endpoints works as expected.

```
# project/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('users.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('transactions.urls')),
    url(r'^auth-token-auth', views.obtain_auth_token),
]

# account/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^accounts/$', AccountListView.as_view()),
     url(r'^accounts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', AccountDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

The question is how to solve this issue by keeping app names `api/v1/[app_name]` in main urls.py. Maybe you can suggest other patterns (best practice) for URL mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version of the URLs correctly terminates the account list pattern, but your first does not.

```
url(r'^$', AccountListView.as_view()),
```